# Resonance Audio, Output to Speakers

Tags: unity-game-engine, resonance-audio

Just started digging around Google's Resonance Audio for Unity and it has promise in headphones.

But I am interested in using for a speaker setup.  I have an ambisonic decoder interface and a speaker array that takes b-format signals.  Is there a way to output a 4-channel / b-format signal directly from Unity so I can monitor Resonance's soundfield in loudspeakers?

At the moment, using SuperCollider / ATK with Unity via OSC for a custom sound engine to allow ambisonic playback in a speaker array.  Works well, but would like to take advantage Google's new tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting a 4-channel b-format signal directly from Unity using the Resonance Audio SDK is only supported when saving directly to a file (.ogg). Streaming the signal directly from Unity to an external ambisonic decoder interface is not currently supported.

If you are interested in the option to record a scene in ambisonic format and save to a file, there are some [scripting functions](https://developers.google.com/resonance-audio/reference/unity/class/resonance-audio-listener) labeled "SoundfieldRecorder" that may help automate the monitoring process, e.g. saving to a custom file path. Ambisonic soundfield recording can also be done manually using the Resoncance Audio Listener component in Unity, which has a Soundfield Recorder UI button to start and stop/save a recording.